# htaccess redirect to subdomain depending on Accept-Language

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I would like to have users redirect to a language subdomain depending on their "Accept-Language" (they will be able to change it later).
Besides others I tried things like

```
RewriteEngine On    
SetEnvIf Accept-Language "([a-z][a-z])" LANGUAGE=$1
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://en.example.org/$1
```

I also tried "RedirectMatch" but couldn't find a way to add conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^en\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en- [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://en.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```